# Find keyCode in other language

Tags: keycode, hebrew

I am building an application designed for Hebrew speakers.

The code `keyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER` gives me the KeyCode for Enter on the english keyboard. How do I find out what is the KeyCode for Enter on the hebrew keybord?

Comment: It should be the same keycode for all keyboards, or not?

Comment: Joblo - it is not... I dont know why.

Comment: Can you specify what kind of application is this? What programming language are you using? Can you try to catch the keycode entered and check what keycode it shows?

Answer (score 0):

Please find it out here by loading this page, focusing the text box and pressing the key you want to investigate (<kbd>Enter</kbd> in your case):

https://www.w3.org/2002/09/tests/keys.html

Comment: It does not work